# Reading multiple REF_CURSORs don't retrieve correct info with Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, oracle, jpa

I'm using Hibernate 5.0.12, and Oracle 12c.
 Calling from a stored procedure that have multiple **REF_CURSOR** output and getResultList always return the same data, no matter how many times getResultList is called.

How do I get the 'next' result list?

Def:

```
@StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.REF_CURSOR, type =Class.class, name = "O_OUTPUT1"),
@StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.REF_CURSOR, type =Class.class, name = "O_OUTPUT2"),
query.execute();
query.getResultList();  // This will return list of values
query.getResultList(); // This returns THE SAME list of values
```

Comment: ErezI am also seeing the same issue, were you able to solve this ?

Comment: It's 2020 and this is still isn't fixed. One would be well advised in avoiding using Hibernate's JPA support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Known Hibernate issue (https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-10616).
I upgraded to 5.2.15 and used index based access via getOutputParameterValue (see https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-11863).
Using EclipseLink also worked, but I wanted to stay with Hibernate.